# how do I get the first letter of every lines from the text file in mrjob mapper in Python?

Tags: python, mrjob

I am new with the python, I am trying to get the first letter of every lines from the text file in Mrjob , below is my code:

```
def mapper(self, key, value):
    numCharacters = len(value.strip().replace(" ",""))
    numWords = len(value.strip().split())
        for word in value.strip().split():
            yield value[0],(numCharacters,numWords)
```

the text.txt file is :

```
      I want to Remove all white      spaces.   
      new lines  and tabs.   
      not the whitespace.
```

When i execute : python text.py text.txt ,
the return of the first letter is the whitespace, not the first letter

```
" "     4.0
" "     4.0
" "     4.0
" "     4.0
" "     4.0
" "     4.0
" "     4.0
" "     4.0
" "     4.0
" "     4.0
" "     4.0
" "     5.67
" "     5.67
" "     5.67
```

This support to be :

```
"I"     4.0
"I"     4.0
"I"     4.0
"I"     4.0
"I"     4.0
"I"     4.0
"I"     4.0
"n"     4.0
"n"     4.0
"n"     4.0
"n"     4.0
"n"     5.67
"n"     5.67
"n"     5.67
```

What is wrong with my code ? please help me to shed the light . Thanks

Comment: Instead of value[0] do value.strip()[0]

Comment: Thank you very much . It works . I thought strip() in loop will remove the whitespace. Neverthought I have to strip one more time.

Comment: the result say : index error : string index out of range .